# Parâmetros com Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

ola, estou tentando passar por parâmetros com variáveis informações de dois campos Dropdown, porém não estou conseguindo utilizar duas variáveis, quando utilizo apenas uma consigo normalmente. segue exemplo:

```
$(function(){
$('#alerta_cor').hide();
$('#id_cod_item').change(function(){
if( $(this).val() ) {
$('#cor_prod').hide();
$('#alerta_cor').show();
$.getJSON('select_cor_prod.php?search=',{id_cod_item: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
var options = '<option value="">Escolha a Cor</option>';
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
options += '<option value="' + j[i].id_cor + '">' + j[i].desc_cor + '</option>';
}
$('#id_cor_prod').html(options).show();
$('#alerta_cor').hide();
});
} else {
$('#id_cor_prod').html('<option value="">– Escolha o produto –</option>');
}
});
```

o problema é quando tento passar duas variáveis não apresenta as informações, ou seja não funciona, não tenho muita habilidade com ajax, por isso creio que esteja fazendo algo erro na declaração das variaveis.
Abaixo segue a linha que alterei para carregar duas variáveis, sendo elas id_cod_item e situacao_prod.

```
$.getJSON('select_cor_prod.php?search=',{id_cod_item: $(this).val(), situacao_prod: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
```

se alguém puder orientar o que estou fazendo de errado agradeço.

att
Ebert

Comment: Por que esse `?search=` na URL se não está passando nenhum valor? Use o callback `.fail(function(){})` conforme descrito na [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) para ver o que está retornando.

Comment: ola, ele passa o valor do input ID="id_cod_item", o problema esta sendo informar mais de uma ID para passar valores.